# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

I am accessing images from another website. I am getting this Error:

> "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request " error when copying 'some(not all)' images. here is my code.

```
$img=$_GET['img']; //another website url
$file=$img;

function getFileextension($file) {
       return end(explode(".", $file));
}
$fileext=getFileextension($file);
if($fileext=='jpg' || $fileext=='gif' || $fileext=='jpeg' || $fileext=='png' || $fileext=='x-png' || $fileext=='pjpeg'){
if($img!=''){
$rand_variable1=rand(10000,100000);
              $node_online_name1=$rand_variable1."image.".$fileext;

                $s=copy($img,"images/".$node_online_name1);
```

}

Comment: Is this all of your code to reproduce the problem?  There's an unclosed curly brace at the end.  Also, where are you actually sending a request to a web server?  When you get the error, what is the request?

Comment: i am copying images from another site. when ever copy function executes then i am getting this error. $s=copy($img,"images/".$node_online_name1);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think preg_replace make more better sense as it will work with latest versions of the PHP as  ereg_replace didn't worked for me being deprecated

```
$url = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $url);
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, but it was solve by

```
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
```

Thanks Cello_Guy for the post.

Answer (score 8):

The only issue I can think of is spaces being in the url, most likely in the file name. All spaces in a url need to be converted to their proper encoding, which is %20.

If you have a file name like this:

"http://www.somewhere.com/images/img 1.jpg"

You would get the above error, but with this:

"http://www.somewhere.com/images/img%201.jpg"

You should have to problems.

Just use the `str_replace()` to replace the spaces (" ") for their proper encoding ("%20")

It looks like this:

```
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
```

For more information on the `str_replace()` check out [The PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: Better than str_replace would be calling urlencode on the "img 1" string

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `rawurlencode()`

Encodes the given string according to » RFC 3986.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Even a trailing blank in the url can cause php file($url) to fail. In recent versions of php or apache even a trailing blank in the url will cause the error. So the url appears to work in a browser because the browser knows enough to %20 the trailing blank or ignore it. That was my error anyway.

Older LAMP allowed it. (ie. same code ran ok). Easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL has some spaces or other special characters, you need to encode it, use urlencode() function